# Find numeric value in csv

Tags: php

I need to check if a particular numeric id is in a given string or comma separated values.

```
$myVal = 20;
```

String could contain just a single value of several, separated by commas

```
$str = 20; 
// $str = 20, 33, 5; 
// $str = 220, 33, 5, 4420;
```

Originally I thought of using strpos, but 20 could be found in 22, or 4420, in the example above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use in_array and explode:

```
$str = '10, 20, 30, 40';
if(in_array(20, explode(', ', $str))) echo 'In Array';
else echo 'Not In Array';
```

Note that I am using the numeric 20 because it will equal the ' 20' value. If I used '20', it will not match ' 20'.

Comment: [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) is probably better than `implode()` in this case

Comment: `20` or `'20'` match, doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes. It is. I have never used that function before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [explode](http://php.net/explode) to split the string into an array. Something like:

```
$parts = explode(',', $str);
```

Then you could use in_array on that.

If you're reading a file, take a look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).